# Can't add block below add to cart button

Tags: magento2, module, layout, blocks, template

I am new to Magento and would like to add a custom block underneath the 'Add to Cart' button.

Here is my catalog_product_view.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">

            <block
                    class="Vendor\ProductPage\Block\Product"
                    name="product.info.customblock"
                    after="product.info.addtocart"
                    template="Vendor_ProductPage::catalog/product/view/custom_block.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

I have tried clearing my cache, re-compiling Magento, different file names and locations for my template file.

My template file is found in
`Vendor/ProductPage/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/custom_block.phtml`

My layout file is found in
`Vendor/ProductPage/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

Any suggestions would be great!

Many thanks
Pete

Comment: Hey Peter, everything looks good, it should render the block. Do you get any errors? Also, some stupid checks like the module is enabled? Try a different browser, not the one you are usually working with, I've had funny caching issues with Magento when using the same browser. Try to add a simple phtml file (maybe a js alert) inside a default.xml in your module, just to make sure that everything is working properly from inside your module.

Comment: Hi Dan. Thanks for getting back. I had tried a combination of different file names (removing special characters), module is enabled as I managed to extend other layouts, just not this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to call the custom block below the add to cart button.

```
  <referenceContainer name="product.info.extrahint">
        <block
                class="Vendor\ProductPage\Block\Product"
                name="product.info.customblock"
                template="Vendor_ProductPage::catalog/product/view/custom_block.phtml"
                before="-"
        >
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```